# Pages: Cannot move some Alignment Guides around

Tags: pages, iwork

With Pages, I'd love to move some of the alignment guides, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

The first and the third one seem to be fixed and cannot be moved around. I can only move the second, which seems to tie to specific text lines or paragraphs.

I checked the Format pane and all its tabs but failed to find anything that relates to those.

But I found that the built-in templates all use those alignment guides at different locations along the ruler. That tells me that they could be customized.

But how? What am I missing here?

Comment: you should probably watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zf_up8NE8R8